# Jmeter - How to keep trying the same request until it succeeds

Tags: jmeter

So right now I have my http request under a while controller and I have a user defined variable Failure set to true. I would like jmeter to keep trying this request until it succeeded (without returned 500). 
My while loop condition is:

```
${__javaScript(${Failure})}
```

I also tried ${Failure} as while condition but getting the same result.

And I have a JSR223 Assertion after the result tree as following:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("500") == true) {
    vars.put("Failure", true)
}
else { 
    vars.put("Failure", false)
}
```

When I ran this, I got into infinite loop even my request succeeded. It seems the Failure value was never updated. Any suggestion on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. In my JSR233 assertion, I updated it to:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode().equals("500")) {
    vars.put("Failure", "true")
}
else { 
    vars.put("Failure", "false")
}
```

And it works now.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're trying to add a [Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) object into a function which expects a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). In order to be able to store a Boolean value into a JMeter Variable you need to use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function instead like:

```
vars.putObject("Failure", true)
```

or surround `true` with quotation marks so it would look like a String to Groovy:

```
vars.put("Failure", "true");
```

1. Amend your JSR223 Assertion code to look like:

   ```
   if (ResponseCode.equals("500")) {
       vars.put("Failure", "true")
   }
   else { 
       vars.put("Failure", "false")
   }
   ```
2. Amend your While Controller condition to be just `${Failure}`. Using JavaScript is a form of a performance anti-pattern, if you need to perform some scripting - go for [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). In particular your case you can just use `${Failure}` variable as the condition given it can be either `true` or `false`

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I updated my assertion and while condition as you suggested, but the value of failure still remain unchanged and my loop is still going infinitely while the response returned 404 which should cause the value of Failure change to false.